# Dialogue in Master's thesis

Tags: masters, writing-style

In some works, as
[What the Tortoise said to Achilles](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article-abstract/IV/14/278/1046872),
[GEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) or [Invariant Risk Minimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02893), some ideas are conveyed by a dialogue. I find this both informative and entertaining.

I would like to use a dialogue to introduce the main ideas of my Master's dissertation, however I am unsure how this would be received in the academic community. I know that jokes should be avoided and I'm not sure whether this would be treated as such.

> Can I use a dialogue in Master's thesis *introduction* to sketch the main ideas?

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: It seems like an interesting and novel idea - making your results available for a wider audience is one of the pillars of academia...

Comment: Why do you assume the academic community cares about your master thesis?

Comment: Do you have homepage? If yes, you could put the dialogue there with links to your master thesis or other places where to find out more about the material. People would more likely come by chance across such a document than a master thesis.

Comment: I try to understand whether the thesis committee will like this solution or not, hence I try to collect your (academic community) opinions on this.

Comment: There will always be some people who do not like this. A plain boring thesis is surely the safest bet.

Comment: @user111388 I see... Thank you!